# Reduce a list of 2-dicts, to a list unique by the one item, concatenating the other items in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to transform some data:

```
[
 {'delim_type': '', 'arcana_list': 'Life 3'}, 
 {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Mind 3'}, 
 {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Prime 3'},
]
```

To look like this:

```
[
 {'delim_type': '', 'arcana_list': 'Life 3'}, 
 {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': ['Mind 3', 'Prime 3']}, 
]
```

Basically where the delim type is the same, append one of the `arcana_list` items to the other.

I've tried to look up ziping and chain iter and stuff, but I can't find a short pythonic way of doing this without unpacking this and then repacking it. I feel it should be do-able with list comprehension, but my python-fu is weak.

Comment: Why not just use `{"and/or": ['Mind 3', 'Prime 3']}` as your dict format? Is there some reason you need that particular structure? Of course you can do the grouping, but you'll have to iterate the entire list to fetch something by `delim_type` next time you want to get values ~ which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: @user3467349 as a list value.  That works too.  I'll update requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
 {'delim_type': '', 'arcana_list': 'Life 3'}, 
 {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Mind 3, Prime 3'}, 
]
```

What I would do unless you were stuck with the above format:

Would be the following format (which allows for much easier lookups):

```
{' and/or ': ["mind 3", "prime 3"], 
' ': 'Prime 3'}
```

This can be done very easily:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list) 
for node in my_list: 
    d[node['delim_type']].append(node['arcana_list'])
```

You can of course do `defaultdict(str)` and `+= ', '` if strings are preferable to a list (though I'm not sure when that would be).

Example:

```
my_list = [
 {'delim_type': '', 'arcana_list': 'Life 3'}, 
 {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Mind 3'}, 
 {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Prime 3'},
]
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'': ['Life 3'], ' and/or ': ['Mind 3', 'Prime 3']})
```

usage:

```
In [19]: d['']
Out[19]: ['Life 3']

In [20]: d[' and/or ']
Out[20]: ['Mind 3', 'Prime 3']
```

Comment: Looks pretty slick! My format comes from regex and using `finditer`, so unless you can convert between mine and yours I'm stuck

Comment: The code below will convert from the code you started with to a `dict` with `delim_type` as it's primary keys, I'll add some example output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a slicker way to do this, but here's what I came up with

```
def combineDicts(old):
    from itertools import groupby
    new = []
    for k,g in groupby(l, lambda i: i['delim_type']):
        d = {'delim_type':k}
        d['arcana_list'] = ', '.join(i['arcana_list'] for i in g)
        new.append(d)
    return new
```

Testing

```
>>> old = [
            {'delim_type': '', 'arcana_list': 'Life 3'}, 
            {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Mind 3'}, 
            {'delim_type': ' and/or ', 'arcana_list': 'Prime 3'},
          ]

>>> combineDicts(old)
[{'arcana_list': 'Life 3', 'delim_type': ''},
 {'arcana_list': 'Mind 3, Prime 3', 'delim_type': ' and/or '}]
```